# Can I have env vars in the python string for file path

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables

I'd like to add a folder to PATH on Windows with this call:

```
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages')
```

However my interpreter gives me a bunch of errors (py 3.7.13).
Is there a way I can have Windows env vars in the path string referenced in such exotic manner?

Comment: I don't think you can use the variable name directly in the path.  You'll have to fetch the env var first, then use the fetched value to construct the path.

Comment: I have to clarify that errors go not from the line I posted but from the following imports I have in my py file. Those imports are modules from the py3.7 installed on the system.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended with a solution like this

```
sys.path.append(f'C:\\Users\\{os.environ.get("USERNAME")}\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\Lib\\site-packages')
```

I had to change '\' to '\\' because I use formatted output f'' to insert username into the string.